# How can i check if an input field is empty or not when a variable is inserted in this field by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if an input field is empty or not and then add/remove class from another element (div). As it is now i am using jquery "input" handler so i can check if the field is empty or not when someone is typing text in it or even if he is copy/paste something in there.

My issue is that when i try to pass text in the field using the code below it doesnt work as it should.

Kindly check my code below:

```js
$('.home-page-address-field').on('input', function(){
    if($('#s').val() == '' ) {
    $("#location-btn").addClass('disable2');
  }else {
    $("#location-btn").removeClass('disable2');
  }

});

var cityA = "London";
alert('The var "cityA" will be inserted to the field and the class "disable2" should be removed from the Browse button but it is not !');

$(function () {
  $('.home-page-address-field').val(cityA);
});
```

```css
.home-page-address-field {
  height:30px;
  margin-right:15px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:0px 8px;
}


.browse-button {
  padding:5px;
  height:25px;
  background:#0088cc;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
}

.disable2{
  opacity:0.4;
  pointer-events:none;
  background:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="s" placeholder="Enter your city..." class="home-page-address-field"/>

<div id="location-btn" class="disable2 browse-button">BROWSE</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `val()` programatically doesn't trigger any event handlers. For that, you can use `.trigger()`:

```js
$('.home-page-address-field').on('input', function(){
    if($('#s').val() == '' ) {
    $("#location-btn").addClass('disable2');
  }else {
    $("#location-btn").removeClass('disable2');
  }

});

var cityA = "London";
alert('The var "cityA" will be inserted to the field and the class "disable2" should be removed from the Browse button but it is not !');

$(function () {
  $('.home-page-address-field').val(cityA).trigger('input');
});
```

```css
.home-page-address-field {
  height:30px;
  margin-right:15px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:0px 8px;
}


.browse-button {
  padding:5px;
  height:25px;
  background:#0088cc;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
}

.disable2{
  opacity:0.4;
  pointer-events:none;
  background:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="s" placeholder="Enter your city..." class="home-page-address-field"/>

<div id="location-btn" class="disable2 browse-button">BROWSE</div>
```

Comment: wow! that was so fast! I was trying to solve this for the last 2 hours !!! Thanks buddy.